# Irreducibility over a field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $K$ be a field, and let $f,g\in K[Y]$ be coprime with $\deg(fg)\geq1$.
How do I prove that $f-gX\in K(X)[Y]$ is irreducible?

I tried the "generic" approach of assuming the existence of a decomposition $f-gX=ab$ with non-units $a,b\in K(X)[Y]$, but this quickly exploded when trying to derive a contradiction.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gauss' lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)#A_proof_valid_over_any_GCD_domain) applies: if $f-gX$ is reducible in $K(X)[Y]$, then it's reducible in $K[X][Y]$. Why does it apply? Because $K[X]$ is a principal ideal domain.