# irreducibility of polynomial over field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025948/irreducibility-over-a-field-of-rational-functions)

This is an exercise from Dummit and Foote where the following hint is also given : $\mathbf{(K[X])(Y)=(K[Y])(X)}$. 
Does this mean that we can consider our polynomial over $\mathbf K[Y]$ with variable X now which will imply that it is irreducible being a linear polynomial and hence irreducible in the required field $\mathbf K(X)$? If I have misunderstood please guide me through the next step.

Comment: Like egreg says in his answer. We can apply the Gauss Lemma to the polynomial ring $R[Y]$, because $R=K[X]$ is a PID, since $K$ is a field. If you want, rename $R[Y]$ to $R[x]$, if this looks more familiar to you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes I understand that Gauss Lemma can be applied but how to proceed further in order to conclude its irreducibilty. Gauss Lemma only says irreducibility in one implies irreducibility in another. I am sure I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In another answer it is given that we have to use the fact that P and Q are relatively prime in order to show that the linear polynomial in X is irreducible as K[Y] is not a field. But how do I use it?

Comment: Understood. Thanks